# Lagrange's theorem of |AN| group where N normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

Here is the problem. I'm a little confused on how to show this. I understand completely why this is true when (A$\cap$N)={e} but when the size is greater than 1 I don't understand why it works.

Is this even the right way to show this?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that this equality is even true when $N$ is not normal subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the second isomorphism theorem,

$$\frac{AN}{N} \cong \frac{A}{A \cap N}.$$

Therefore

$$\frac{\vert AN \vert}{\vert N \vert} = \frac{\vert A \vert}{\vert A \cap N \vert},$$

so just multiply through by $\vert N \vert$ to get the result you want.